# How to plot an histogram with y as a sum of the x values for every bin in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a pv dataframe containing information regarding solar plants. One variable is the generation power in kw:

```
id   power
1    20.1
2    110.1
3    3.0
4    231.9
...
```

I'm trying to plot an histogram with power as X values with a binwidth of 50 kW. As Y I would like to show the cumulative power for every plant in the range of the bin.
I tried this code without success.

```
ggplot(pv, aes(x = power, y = sum(power)), stat = "bin") + 
    geom_histogram(stat = "identity", binwidth=50)
```

I need to calculate the sum by using the cut function or it is possible to generate this graph directly with ggplot2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id=1:100, power=rlnorm(100, log(100)))
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x=power, weight=power), binwidth=50) +
  ylab("Total Power (kW)")
```

The `weight` aesthetic forces the stat calculation to multiply each count by the corresponding weight, which in this case is equivalent to summing the power values.

[image]

And here is a better visualization:

```
ggplot(transform(df, power.bin=cut(power, 0:24 * 50, include.lowest=TRUE))) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=power.bin, y=power), color="white", position="stack", stat="identity") +
  ylab("Total Power (kW)") + 
  scale_x_discrete(drop=F) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it was easier than I thought.

Comment: @DavideRivola, please see update for what I think is a better way to display this.